# SSH-Tunnel support workaround for pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, pgadmin, ssh-tunnel, pgadmin-4

After installing Vagrant/VirtualBox and connecting to the database via pgAdmin 3 using ssh tunnel, I am warned that it is not compatible with pgAdmin 3. I can still connect but after some time pgAdmin will seemingly randomly shut down. pgAdmin 4 does not have built-in support for ssh tunnel (and won't until version 2.0 comes out).

[image]

Is there a command line workaround to create an ssh tunnel in pgAdmin4?

Comment: Vagrant version 1.9.2, VirtualBox 5.1.18, PosgreSQL 9.5.6

Comment: Can you install a newer PgAdmin-III? Alternately, you can always use `plink` from PuTTY via shortcut file to set up an ssh tunnel, then connect to it from PgAdmin4.

Comment: Check this mail chain ... https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&l=26&q=PG-Admin+4+-+SSH-Tunneling

Comment: Updated link, as that one only finds messages in the past year (which we are creeping out of).

https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&q=PG-Admin+4+-+SSH-Tunneling&l=26&d=-1&s=r